# Synchronous signals using Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm having two functions whose time computations are the same. The first takes around 2 seconds to show a result. The second is the same.

But when I display the different results, it takes the sum of time computation and make the result be displayed in parallel (for the two functions) in 4 seconds (and not 2 seconds for each one)

```
QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(capture()));
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(capture_2()));
timer->start(0);
```

How can I establish a call to make it work in 2 seconds each?

Comment: Did you use threads? If those functions are in the same thread, they are not executed in parallel but sequentially.

Comment: I'm not using threads. Shall I do it with OpenMP?

Comment: You could, but you don't have to. Since you're using Qt you could use QThreads too, which i would recommend.

Comment: But how much computing do those functions do? 2 seconds each seems a bit to small. Creating threads will have an overhead and most likely it will take more time than with the serial version.

Comment: @AdriC.S. Yes, even with OpenMP it would give me more time than the sequential code that I have written above!

Comment: Good point! I was fixed to the idea, that those functions have to run in parallel...

Comment: What about the typo error on the 2nd connect Signal?

Comment: @fanl I didn't get your point.

Comment: Can you show your output code and outputed data?

Comment: I mean, there is and "E" missing on the timeout word. `connect(timer, SIGNAL(tim"E"out()), this, SLOT(capture_2()));`

Comment: @fanl Thanks. I have mistyped it. It's edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a couple new workers, link them to [QThreads](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html) and connect your signals to slots on each worker. The trick is to pass the flag Qt::QueuedConnection to connect, so the calls are made at the same time on both threads. And don't worry, this won't incurr a two seconds overhead.

```
class Worker1 : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT;
public slots:
    void capture(void);
}

class Worker2 : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT;
public slots:
    void capture(void);
}


void setup( void )
{
Worker1 * w1 = new Worker1;
Worker2 * w2 = new Worker2;

QThread * t1 = new QThread( w1 );
QThread * t2 = new QThread( w2 );

w1->moveToThread( t1 );
w2->moveToThread( t2 );

t1->start();
t2->start();

QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), w1, SLOT(capture()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), w2, SLOT(capture()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
timer->start(0);
}
```

Disclaimer: I made up this code on the spot, it may need some polish but I hope you get my meaning.

Comment: `this won't incurr a two seconds overhead.` Why? Does `Qt` optimize the creation of the threads? With a threadpool maybe? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @AdriC.S. I had forgotten to add call to QThread::start. Now it should be clear; the threads are already running and in a wait state. The signal will simply wake them up.